# What does these syntax mean in Android studio suggestions?

Tags: android

[image: screenshot]

What does it mean.
Second one I understand, it's expecting a View.OnclickListner. What does l: means ?

Also what about l: ((View!) -> Unit)?)

Answer (score 1):

It means is a lamda expression that does not return a type, hence the Unit. You can put code inside it that will act when the user clicks.  You could write, for example a reusable Alert Dialog that gets as parameter a whole function that doesn't return anything and you can reuse it. Like this:

```
fun showDialog(context: Context, message:String, retry:() ->Unit){
        val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(context)
        builder.setTitle("Error")
        builder.setMessage(message)
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK"){_,_ ->
            builder.create().dismiss()
        }
        builder.setNeutralButton("Retry"){_,_ ->
            retry()
            builder.create().dismiss()

        }
        builder.create().show()
    }
```

And in your actvities you can call it like this:

```
fun displayView(){
//some code
}

showDialog(context, "Error displaying view", displayView())
```

This way, when the alertDialog shows and the user clicks on retry, the displayView() function would be call or any other that you pass as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

When use kotlin, this means suggest you use [lambdas](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html). If we create an  anonymous class such as **OnClickListener**. The common way is :

```
view.setOnClickListener(object : View.OnClickListener {
    override fun onClick(v: View?) {
        toast("Hello World")
    }
})
```

And the recommened way(lambdas) is:

```
view.setOnClickListener() { v -> toast("Hello World") }
```

You can see the second way is more concise.

Answer (score 0):

Any time a method calls for the implementation of an interface that contains a single abstract method (or SAM), Java/Kotlin can replace that implementation with a lambda. This applies to the method in the OP, or in `setOnClickListener`.